# Password manager which gets unlocked by logging in into your session other than GNOME Keyring

Tags: password, pam, shadow

Windows has a neat feature: it has a built-in password manager/storage which gets unlocked automatically when you log in.

Are there any Linux applications which are linked to `pam.d`, so that entering your *valid* password is enough to get their stored passwords unlocked/unecrypted?

A bonus feature would be to be able to run something like `password=$(password_manager --item certain_item --show)`.

AFAIK there's gnome-keyring but what if I don't use Gnome?

There's a feature request for keepassxc but it's not implemented yet: https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/discussions/5879

Comment: There's [KDE Wallet](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KDE_Wallet#Unlock_KDE_Wallet_automatically_on_login) too. But why *not* use GNOME Keyring? I don't think it's too heavily dependent on GNOME. It's nicer if you use GNOME Shell certainly, but still works with, say Xfce.

Comment: I've zero Gnome related applications installed. What is Gnome's password manager which uses Gnome keyring? `dnf search keyring` only shows `gnome-keyring-sharp.x86_64 : Mono implementation of GNOME Keyring` which requires a metric ton of dependencies which I'm reluctant to install (mono). KWallet wants to install 350MB (!) worth of dependencies (252MB with `--setopt=install_weak_deps=False`). Nope, not for me :-)

Comment: Not sure what it's called these days with all the GNOME renaming going on, but it used to be called Seahorse. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/seahorse

Comment: Seahorse only stores these types of items 1) Secure Shell Key 2) GPG key 3) Private Key 4) "Import from file".  Not exactly what I need. I want to store passwords and probably binary files.

Comment: Where did you see that? It's essentially a fronted to GNOME Keyring, and it can store passwords just fine. IIRC even Google Chrome on Linux supports it for storing passwords (the way it uses the system store in macOS and Windows).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHsG0.png

Comment: Ah wait, you may need to first create a "keyring" in which to store the passwords. In distros which have the "unlock on login" configured, this keyring creation is done on account creation

Comment: I've no idea how to create a keyring. Seahorse doesn't seemingly have this option.

Comment: I don't have a PC on hand to check, but I'll look that up when I do

Comment: On my system, Seahorse shows a “Login” password keyring (which is the one that gets unlocked when I log in), and in there I can add keys (GPG and SSH) but also stored passwords. To create a keyring, use “File” / “New” and select “Password Keying”.

Comment: There's no File -> New -> Password Keyring in SeaHorse 43.0 :-( See the above screenshot

Comment: Right, it’s the + button, on my Fedora system it shows a “Password keying” entry. Perhaps you need to start `gnome-keying` first.

Comment: `dnf whatprovides '*/gnome-keying'` -> `Error: No matches found.`

Comment: It works better if you don’t drop the `r` in `keyring` ;-).

Comment: LMAO.... I copied-pasted what you wrote, Stephen :-)

Comment: Ha ha yes indeed, sorry, `gnome-keyring`.

Comment: After `sudo dnf install gnome-keyring; systemctl --user start gnome-keyring-daemon.service` everything now works. Thanks! Seahorse without gnome-keyring is pretty useless. I spoke too soon: I re-relog-in'ed and I still need to enter my login password in SeaHorse to unlock it. Something is missing.

Comment: Anyways that warrants a new question.